# modelsummary omits negative sign in front of coefficients

Tags: r, modelsummary

I've searched the modelsummary website and the internet. I also tried library(conflicted) to see if there is a package conflict. Modelsummary seems to omit negative signs in front of coefficients. Instead the coefficients that should be negative are underlined. Please advise.

Comment: What is your locale/language? Can you try calling `options("modelsummary_format_numeric_html" = "plain")` before creating the table?

Comment: It works now that I called that before it. Thanks!  I had changed locale using fix_windows_histograms() to get skimr histograms to work. Maybe that messed with it?

Comment: Thanks @thirdci, that's useful info! See my answer for some more details you may want to consider.

Answer (score 1):

`modelsummary` inserts "proper" minus signs (unicode) to display negative numbers. In some locales/languages, this may cause display problems. You can disable this behavior by calling:

```r
options("modelsummary_format_numeric_html" = "plain")
```

Future versions of `modelsummary` may use smart detection to do this automatically when necessary. Follow development here:

https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/modelsummary/issues/552

Note that, in general, I discourage users to change their locales for the sole purpose of making unicode inline histograms work (see the user's comment above). Instead, the recommended approach is to call `datasummary_skim()` or follow the instructions here:

https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/datasummary.html#histograms